# Trying to parse a .dat file and stores to 2-D array in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I have an example to parse a similar format file:
Data example (.data):

```
+ Naoki Abe
- Myriam Abramson
+ David W. Aha
+ Kamal M. Ali
- Eric Allender
```

And here is the python example for store the code into a 2D array:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer='path/to/.data/file', 
    header=None, 
    sep=',')

# separate names from classes
vals = df.loc[:,:].values
names = [n[0][2:] for n in vals]
cls = [n[0][0] for n in vals]
```

From my understanding, this python code means the data will be variable `df` and extracts the string data associated with each person in the `vals` variable. And then, it splits the strings of `vals`  into `names` and `cls`. And The `names` and `cls` lists should hold those components such that the ith person's name will be in `names[i]` and their associated class in `cls[i]`.

However, when I want to use the similar way to parse another similar dataset (.dat),

```
-1  this is comment1 blah blah blah (it is a big paragraph)
-1  this is comment2 blah blah blah (it is a big paragraph)
-1  this is comment3 blah blah blah (it is a big paragraph)
```

Therefore, I modified example to be like:

```
# read in the dataset
df = pd.read_csv(
    engine='python',
    filepath_or_buffer='data/Pro1/train.dat', 
    header=None, 
    sep='\t+')

# separate names from classes
vals = df.loc[:,:].values
comm = [n[0][2:] for n in vals]
rates = [n[:1][0] for n in vals]
```

I got error message: `TypeError: 'long' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` at `comm = [n[0][2:] for n in vals]`
I searched for the error message, it explained that it means I was trying to store an int into string (?). I am trying to store the whole paragraph of comment and it is a string. And in the example, it stored a string of name just fine. 
Another question I have is since I had to parse a `.dat` file, I am guessing it is `TAB` behind `-1` instead of space, I am not sure if the range of array I set is correct.**

My experience: I am not an expert of python as you probably has figured, I can definitely read the code but have to do researches along the way when writing it. Python is my only choice right now to do such data analysis.

Answer (score 0):

There are no comma separators in the first file and, therefore, each line in the file results in a single string, for example, '+ Naoki Abe'. Consequently, you are able to use string slicing to separate the names from the rest of the strings.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', header=None, sep=',')
>>> vals = df.loc[:,:].values
>>> vals
array([['+ Naoki Abe'],
       ['- Myriam Abramson'],
       ['+ David W. Aha'],
       ['+ Kamal M. Ali'],
       ['- Eric Allender']], dtype=object)
>>> names = [n[0][2:] for n in vals]
>>> names
['Naoki Abe', 'Myriam Abramson', 'David W. Aha', 'Kamal M. Ali', 'Eric Allender']
>>> cls = [n[0][0] for n in vals]
>>> cls
['+', '-', '+', '+', '-']
```

I too suspected that there is a tab character separating the -1 from the rest of each line. The result is that pandas splits each line at the tab. In this case you can't use string slicing once you've declared the tab as a separator.

```
>>> df2 = pd.read_csv('temp2.csv', engine='python', header=None, sep='\t')
>>> vals2 = df2.loc[:,:].values
>>> vals2
array([[-1, 'this is comment1 blah blah blah (it is a big paragraph)'],
       [-1, 'this is comment2 blah blah blah (it is a big paragraph)'],
       [-1, 'this is comment3 blah blah blah (it is a big paragraph)']], dtype=object)
>>> first = [val[0] for val in vals2]
>>> first
[-1, -1, -1]
>>> second = [val[1] for val in vals2]
>>> second
['this is comment1 blah blah blah (it is a big paragraph)', 'this is comment2 blah blah blah (it is a big paragraph)', 'this is comment3 blah blah blah (it is a big paragraph)']
```

**But do not despair!**

There's a way that both data files can be handles in a similar way.

Use `sep='\s+'` so that tabs and spaces are handled similarly. Then pandas will turn each line into a list of strings. All you need to do now is to pick off the first item and to reassemble the others.

```
>>> df3 = pd.read_csv('temp2.csv', engine='python', header=None, sep='\s+')
>>> vals3 = df3.loc[:,:].values
>>> vals3
array([[-1, 'this', 'is', 'comment1', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', '(it', 'is',
        'a', 'big', 'paragraph)'],
       [-1, 'this', 'is', 'comment2', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', '(it', 'is',
        'a', 'big', 'paragraph)'],
       [-1, 'this', 'is', 'comment3', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', '(it', 'is',
        'a', 'big', 'paragraph)']], dtype=object)
>>> first = [val[0] for val in vals3]
>>> first
[-1, -1, -1]
>>> second = [' '.join(val[1:]) for val in vals3]
>>> second
['this is comment1 blah blah blah (it is a big paragraph)', 'this is comment2 blah blah blah (it is a big paragraph)', 'this is comment3 blah blah blah (it is a big paragraph)']
```

My final remark: I question your use of pandas over the csv module.